# SimpleXML generating errors with valid XML strings

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, simplexml

I'm new to SimpleXML with Codeigniter in PHP 5.2.6 and have received the error below. No matter what I tried I can not get any output from the parser.

I've checked that the XML is valid. I've confirmed that the string is populated with the XML and  also have substituted other valid XML strings to confirm.

I'm fairly new in this particular area so any help would be wonderful.

Error message:

Message: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 12:   parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

Code sample:

```
$xmlClean = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$xmlData = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlClean);
echo $xmlData->person[0]->id;
```

Comment: Can you show us the xml?

Comment: Personally, I use DOMDocument.  It works similar to Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue with the following:

```
$string = <<<XML
$xml
XML;
```

Just wrapping the $xml like this then allowed this to work:

```
$xmlData = simplexml_load_string($string);
var_dump($xmlData);
```

Hope someone finds this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was having some trouble with SimpleXML objects myself... What I realized was that the values of the XML elements are not strings, buy SimpleXML objects themselves...

To walk around this problem, when I wanted to use the strings of the SimpleXML object, converting the object to an associative array with get_object_vars.

```
$data = get_object_vars($xml);

echo $data['element1']; //Outputs the value of the element1 element
```